# Switching Anaconda Environment while Jupyter Notebook is running

Tags: jupyter-notebook, anaconda, virtual-environment

I use Anaconda Navigator in order to use Jupyter notebooks. I am working on `notebook1.ipynb` in the Environment `env1`. While I was running a cell in `notebook1.ipynb`, I tried to switch to the `base` environment in order to work on another project. Anaconda navigator however is taking forever to make this switch, and won't let me cancel it either.

I was curious if this error occurred because I was running `notebook1.ipynb` in the `env1` environment, meaning that I could not switch out of this environment? Of if this functionality is supposed to be possible and my error is likely coming from a different source?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my experience, switching conda environments in Anaconda navigator always takes a long time. Have you tried opening a new anaconda prompt and activated the environment from there?

I am running code in notebook and pycharm (different environments) at the same time, so it should be possible

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes switching conda environments in Anaconda navigator always takes a long time, but this was getting excessive. in The end I closed Anaconda prompt (though my notebook somehow kept running), and then reopened and was able to switch just fine. I will try your suggestion of having two anaconda prompts open at the same time though.

Comment: Strange. I just tried again and was able to switch just fine. Must have been a different issue.